# What to do when you're forced to code under bad coding (design) standards

Tags: team, coding-standards

This isn't about the typical naming conventions, where to place your comments, should we use regions, etc.  This is about a coding standard that discusses specifics on how a programmer should design his applications.

Stuff like: (on a .NET app and not in the exact wordings)

- Make as few classes possible
- Classes should do as much as their real world counterparts can
- Modification is better than extension
- One DLL per category (One library for email functions, one library for File related functions)

Everyone's had their experience with bad code and possibly bad design, but what if you were placed in a team (leaving is not an option) where they had design standards that just don't feel right.  I'm unsure how to respond professionally when I feel like I'm dying inside whenever I'm asked to code this way.

Comment: I don't even care that this is old as hell, I had to say it: Reading that list almost gave me an anxiety attack.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't know who said this originally, but when faced with a situation that you don't like, there are only three options:

1. Change it.
2. Accept it.
3. Leave it.

Do you have the energy and influence within the company to make the mammoth effort to try the first option? Do you want to write better code by stealth and risk being fired?

Can you accept the situation and write code to those "standards?" My advice, don't do this unless you really need the paycheck. It will slowly chip away at your morale.

Which leaves option 3. Even if you need to accept the situation in the short term, you should start looking elsewhere for another job.